# Support for AWS member accounts

Tags: amazon-web-services

How to get support enabled for AWS member accounts? Having created the accounts through AWS organisations only role-based access is possible, how can I change the support plan?

Comment: Just found [this link](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=89484) to the AWS forum - It really seems someone has to "recover" the root password first?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm sad but you really have to **recover your root account password** first to gain access to your root user, before you can opt for a support plan change.

This is not only a security backdrop but a not needed extra hop. Not cool AWS!